# Multi Level Items

Tags: database-design, database-schema

We're trying to build an application that will describe our price list. The price list itself is multi-leveled so a price of an item depends on numerous "options". I think an example would be my best choice here.

Currently I have the following tables:

Item:

- Item_ID  (PK)
- Name

Main_Option:

- Main_Option_ID (PK)
- Name

Sub_Option:

- Sub_Option_ID (PK)
- Main_Option_ID (FK)
- Name

Item_To_Sub_Option

- Item_ID
- Sub_Option_ID

This is the structure that we currently have – here is an example to demonstrate how it works:

Item: Sofa

Main_Option: Length

Sub_Option: 40”-50”

Item_To_Sub_Option:  Sofa's Item_ID, 40”-50” Sub_Option_ID

You get the picture. Up until here it’s pretty straight forward. It basically allows every item to have unlimited amount of sub options and main options.

Now, what we are trying to achieve is a drill down of the described solution, or a multi level options solution.

For instance, a more complex item where I need to generate further options but those options are generated not from the item – but from other sub options. Example as follows:

Item: Sofa

Main_Option: Shape

Sub_Option: 1/2 Circle

"1/2 circle" needs to have an ADDITIONAL Main_Option – “Diameter” which will have Sub_Options (50” Round, 60” Round etc).  These options do not relate directly with the item, but with the sub option “1/2 Circle” that was chosen before on the upper level.

What is the best way to design the database to achieve this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are struggling with this is that you are thinking about the problem in the wrong way a little bit.  Instead of thinking in terms of main options that have sub-options that have other sub-options, you want to think of it in terms of main options that are made up of other main options.

If you think of main options as "features" or "qualities" and sub-options as "values" then this becomes a little clearer.  In your example, a sofa has a quality of "SHAPE".  For your purposes, SHAPE might be LINEAR or ROUND.  Linear shapes have a quality of LENGTH, whereas round has a quality of ANGLE.  None of these qualities have any *values*: SHAPE, LINEAR, ROUND.  However, these qualities: LENGTH, ANGLE do have values.  The values for LENGTH might be things like *40"-50"* and for ANGLE might be *1/2 Circle*.

Your data model therefore doesn't need to change very much:

[image: ERD]

Just add another FK from MAIN_OPTION to itself.  You'll note that this was also suggested by David, except that David suggested this as a poor second choice, whereas in reality it's a good first choice.

Your rules are hierarchical and RDBMS can be awkward for hierarchical data *unless you are drilling down through your hierarchy*.  When you are drilling down then each step is a simple one.

Comment: I realized from David's answer that is no "real answer". Thank you guys, helped me a lot!

Comment: David - Both of your proposed solutions have serious issues.  Your first solution is to walk away from RDBMS and to invent a hierarchical document model that would require the creation of substantial amounts of parsing logic.  You didn't even suggest sticking with something like XML that already has stable library code support.  Your second suggestion is a bigger digression from OP's current model than what I've suggested and doesn't address the distinction between option values and categories of options very clearly.

Comment: Joel - My first suggestion was to model the problem using MongoDB. It is very applicable to this type of data. There is no special parsing involved. It's just a different type of database than the usual relational one. So I dispute the fact that this answer has a "serious issue". I think you're just not familiar with the technology I suggested. I think the relational model I suggested is similar to what you've drawn above. It is a classic part/subpart relationship which needs a self-referential table. I don't think there is a "serious issue" here either.

Comment: David - Suggesting MongoDB for OP's requirement would be like bringing a sledge hammer to swat a fly.  A document model is _much_ too flexible and broad and does not provide one of the primary benefits of RDBMS in OP's scenario.  MongoDB is great for unstructured data or loosely structured data.  OP's data is far from either.  Your assessment of OP's requirements as "classic part/subpart relationship" is flawed in my opinion.  While there is an involution and a many to many relationship, it is _not_ "bill of materials".

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of to go about designing something like this. The first thing to recognise though is that your data is inherently hierarchical in structure, and not necessarily very regular. This means that using a traditional relational database will not be an especially great fit for this type of data. However, it can be done.

The first way that I'd probably use myself, would be to choose a non-relational database such as MongoDB, which is designed to store collections of "documents". A document is essentially a bit like an Object, and can have other embedded documents within in. This would be especially good for your type of data. You could create a data model like this:

```
Item {
   main_options: [{
      name: "Shape",
      sub_options: [{
          name: "1/2 Circle",
          //  Other fields here
      }]
   },
   {
      //  Other main option
   }]
}
```

The beauty of this type of document-based data model is that there is *no* fixed schema you have to adhere to. If an item needs several nested sets of options, you just go right ahead and define that item's document that way. Despite each "item" document being potentially quite different, they all get stored in the same "collection" and you can perform queries to find different items. So you could ask the database to find all items with a "1/2 Circle" sub-option of "Shape", for example.

If you are used to working with relational databases, moving to something like MongoDB is a bit of a mind shift, but I think it would actually suit the nature of your data quite well in this case.

On the other hand, if you absolutely must use a relational database, then you'll need to model things as a hierarchy, which can get a bit tricky. Basically you need tables a bit like you already described, although I've restated them with the changes I'd make here:

```
item (id (pk), name: text, ...)

option (id (pk), owner: option_id (fk), name: text, ...)

item_options (item_id, option_id)
```

So here we define our item table and another table that maps an item to its set of main options, which are defined in the "option" table.

The option table includes an extra field "owner", which for main options, you would set to "null", but for sub-options you'd set this field to the option ID of the main option, or possibly a sub-option that "owns" it. Using this kind of structure, you can nest your options to any depth you like. HEre is some example data:

```
item (1, "Sofa", ...)
option (1, null, "Shape", ...)
option (2, null, "Length", ...)
option (3, 1, "1/2 Circle", ...)
option (4, 1, "3/4 Circle", ...)
option (5, 2, "Short", ...)
option (6, 2, "Long", ...)
option (7, 5, "Specific Short Measurement", ...)
option (8, 5, "Other Short Measurement", ...)
item_options (1, 1)
item_options (1, 2)
```

The downside to using a relational database for this type of data is that the queries to find things are not very easy. For example, to search for all sofas with a "1/2 Circle" option, you might need something like:

```
select * from item i inner join item_options io on i.id = io.item_id inner join option o on io.option_id = o.id left join option o2 on o.id = o2.owner where o.name = 'Shape' and o2.name = '1/2 Circle';
```

As you can see, the deeper your item structure is, the more joins you have to make to query something deep down in the hierarchy.  And that query is just for something with only main and sub-options.

Anyway, I hope this gives you some options for how to model things.

Comment: Lets assume I must go with relational database - Isn't a better structure for this? Does anybody else have a different idea?

Comment: There's no better structure. It's a classic relational database modelling problem. Google for examples of modelling Part and Sub-Part relationships. You'll find the same set of tables as I outlined. The real issue is that your data is hierarchical and irregular (not always the same depth) and is therefore difficult to model in a relational database which is not designed to model such things efficiently. That's why I suggested MongoDB which will be much easier to model things with, but might not be possible to use depending on your circumstances.